# Interactive player on feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to build a custom interactive player that works in the facebook feed when shared, in the likes of [this one](https://stage.interlude.fm/compton/index.html), but as far as I've been able to research it's not something available yet (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779398/does-facebook-allow-embedding-content-in-the-feed-through-some-whitelist) for example), but I also couldn't find any official facebook documentation on it. Does anybody have any insight into that?

Comment: You need to use Flash

Comment: There is no documentation for you on features that you can not use anyway. How to embed swf/mp4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

Comment: I have a similar requirement, have you found a solution to this?